# I have a power bi circular dependency error between too measures

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Daily balance = [Received] + [backlog] - [analyzed]

backlog = var previous balance = calculate ( [Daily balance], Dateadd( Calendar[Date], - 1, Day) ) return  previous balance
```

I have three tables: one for received items, another for processed items, and a calendar table (used to filter the other two by date). I created measures like "received" (number of rows in the received table) and "analyzed" (number of rows in the processed table). For instance, if on day 1, I received 10 processes and processed only 5, my daily balance is 5, and the backlog is 0 (since it's the first day). On day 2, the daily balance from day 1 becomes the backlog for day 2, and the daily balance for day 2 is calculated as analyzed - backlog - backlog.

Comment: Yes, you will do. Measure A is looking at Measure B, and Measure B is looking at Measure A. Update your question with a more info on your data model. You will need to rethink your calculations. For example, could `Daily balance` be `SUM([Receive]) - SUM([Taken away])`

Comment: I have three tables: one for received items, another for processed items, and a calendar table (used to filter the other two by date). I created measures like "received" (number of rows in the received table) and "analyzed" (number of rows in the processed table). For instance, if on day 1, I received 10 processes and processed only 5, my daily balance is 5, and the backlog is 0 (since it's the first day). On day 2, the daily balance from day 1 becomes the backlog for day 2, and the daily balance for day 2 is calculated as analyzed - backlog - backlog.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way, Daily balance = sum of all received upto the given date, minus the sum of all processed upto the given date.

Try the following measures:

```
Received = COUNTROWS('YourReceivedTable')

Analyzed = COUNTROWS('YourProcessedTable')

Daily balance =
  var thisDate = MAX('YourCalendarTable'[Date])
  return
    CALCULATE(
      [Received] - [Analyzed],
      ALL('YourCalendarTable'),
      'YourCalendarTable'[Date] <= thisDate
    )
```

And if you want a Backlog measure then you can have:

```
Backlog = CALCULATE([Daily balance], PREVIOUSDAY('YourCalendarTable'[Date]))
```

Comment: Tks Sam, but you calculated the daily balance as Received minus Analyzed. However, what I actually need is for the daily balance to consider both the backlog and the unanalyzed portion of what's received. So, my revised formula for daily balance is Received + Backlog - Analyzed. This way, the daily balance represents what's left after analyzing both the backlog and a portion of the received amount.

Comment: Say on Mon 10 in 5 done, Tues 10 more in and 5 more done, Wed 10 more in and 5 more done. What's the daily balance at the end of Wednesday? The expression I gave does (10 + 10 +10) - (5 + 5 + 5) = 15

Comment: Any updates on this? Did the answer/comments help?